# can't create wallpaper slideshow in fvwm-crystal

Tags: settings, desktop-background, fvwm

I've got my wallpaper placed into the right directory, but when I select 'Random Wallpaper' from the 'Auto Wallpaper" submenu in 'Preferences", a wallpaper is randomly placed on the screen once and I still have to manually change the wallpaper every so often and I'm not given the opportunity to set an auto-change schedule. What's the deal?

Answer (score 0):

I found the various background changing programs either didn't work or did not work as I liked so I created the following script to run automatically at login:

```
#/bin/bash
find -L ~/Pictures -name  '*.jpg'>~/jpegs.text
while true ; do
    convert `shuf -n 1 jpegs.text` -resize 1920x1080 ~/temp/backgroundtemp.jpg
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///home/john/temp/backgroundtemp.jpg
    cp ~/temp/backgroundtemp.jpg ~/temp/background.jpg
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///home/john/temp/background.jpg
    sleep 60
done
```

All my pics are jpegs in my Pictures folder in many subdirectories. The script at startup creates a jpegs.text file containing path names to all my files then sets a random backgound once every 60 seconds. I have hundreds of pictures of family and our many trips. Don't ask why I use the gsettings command twice on the same file because I don't remember. It may have been for debug purposes but I'm too lazy to figure that out.